# Hyperledger Fabric: Blockchain consistency checks

Tags: hash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I have a few questions on internal consistency checks in HLF. Thanks in advance for any information.

1. Which part of the HLF system keeps track of the consistency of the blockchain?
2. If I were to open the HLF ledger file of a peer (on the docker instance) in a binary editor and change it at one place with a random number (thereby breaking the hash or clobbering the header), which part of the system detects this as a problem? And when?
3. Is such a consistency check done only for the last block while appending the new block? If the change is made to a historic block (ie., not the last one), when is this detected?
4. If such a problem is found, does the damaged copy of the blockchain automatically get rebuilt by the peer?
5. Does a Read also trigger a consistency check (assuming that a Write/Append does)? If a block is damaged and there is no Write for a long time, will intervening Reads report wrong data?